# Implement Routing With EmberFire?

Tags: ember.js, firebase, emberfire

However I find myself still unclear on the prospect of getting some of the functionality as Model.  Right now I'm trying to utilize the new [emberFire](https://github.com/firebase/emberFire) library, which provides some base Object types for interacting with the Firebase service.

I'm able to create new objects and arrays of objects, however I'm unable to get Routes setup properly.

- Am I able to extend my base App.Model as one of the EmberFire objects in order to utilize the more standard approaches to retrieving and manipulating data?

#### Edit

When I've tried using the suggestion in Answer 2, I've gotten this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`

So I tried adding in:

```
App.Post = EmberFire.Object.extend({
  id: null,
  body: null
});
```

To perhaps define the Object, however I feel I'm going about that the wrong way as well?

#### Edit 2

Here's my current stuff:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('post', { path: '/:post_id' }, function() {
        this.route('edit');
     });
});

App.Post = EmberFire.Object.extend({
      id: null,
      title: null
});
```

As I mentioned above, I've tried defining my object as both an `EmberFire.Object` and `EmberFire.Array`, and attempted plugging `App.Post.create` in my Route.

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return EmberFire.Array.create({
      ref: new Firebase("https://embertest2.firebaseio.com/posts/")
    });
  }
});

App.PostRoute = Ember.Router.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return EmberFire.Object.create({
      ref: new Firebase("https://embertest2.firebaseio.com/posts/" + params.post_id)
    });
  }
});
```

I'm also wondering if perhaps I shouldn't be using the `EmberFire.Array` in my IndexRoute to generate essentially the list of links for each post.

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    title: "",
    actions: {
      addPost: function() {
        this.pushObject(this.get('title'));
      }
    }
});
```

My aim currently is to create each Post record, have it populate on the list, have links to each Post, and the ability to edit each Post record on the Post page.

Here's the current error I've been getting:

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined      ember.js:30274
    serialize       ember.js:30274
    paramsForHandler        ember.js:29636
    Router.generate         ember.js:29457
    Ember.Router.Ember.Object.extend.generate       ember.js:30524
    (anonymous function)        ember.js:32438
    ComputedPropertyPrototype.get       ember.js:4446
    get         ember.js:1937
    (anonymous function)        ember.js:20674
    Ember.EnumerableUtils.forEach       ember.js:1805
    Ember.View.Ember.CoreView.extend._applyAttributeBindings        ember.js:20655
    Ember.View.Ember.CoreView.extend.applyAttributesToBuffer        ember.js:21128
    Ember.View.Ember.CoreView.extend.beforeRender       ember.js:21107
    Ember.CoreView.Ember.Object.extend._renderToBuffer      ember.js:19458
    Ember.View.Ember.CoreView.extend._renderToBuffer        ember.js:21096
    superWrapper        ember.js:1239
    (anonymous function)        ember.js:19440
    Ember.Instrumentation.instrument        ember.js:1683
    Ember.CoreView.Ember.Object.extend.renderToBuffer       ember.js:19439
    Ember.merge.appendChild         ember.js:21941
    Ember.View.Ember.CoreView.extend.appendChild        ember.js:21291
    EmberHandlebars.ViewHelper.Ember.Object.create.helper        ember.js:25821
    (anonymous function)        ember.js:25999
    (anonymous function)        ember.js:32685
    program1
    program         handlebars-1.0.0.js:2251
    Ember.View.Ember.CoreView.extend.render         ember.js:20522
    Ember.CoreView.Ember.Object.extend._renderToBuffer      ember.js:19459
    Ember.View.Ember.CoreView.extend._renderToBuffer        ember.js:21096
    superWrapper        ember.js:1239
    (anonymous function)        ember.js:19440
    Ember.Instrumentation.instrument        ember.js:1683
    Ember.CoreView.Ember.Object.extend.renderToBuffer       ember.js:19439
    Ember.merge.renderToBufferIfNeeded      ember.js:21887
    Ember.View.Ember.CoreView.extend.renderToBufferIfNeeded         ember.js:21103
    Ember.merge.ensureChildrenAreInDOM      ember.js:22563
    Ember.ContainerView.Ember.View.extend._ensureChildrenAreInDOM       ember.js:22528
    DeferredActionQueues.flush      ember.js:5484
    Backburner.end      ember.js:5568
    (anonymous function)        ember.js:5822
```

I figure I'm doing something silly here, and will continue to muck about until I stumble over what I did incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

The README on the emberFire page that you linked details how to create your custom objects in your `Route`.  If you're talking about the `Router` (which is different than a `Route`), I don't think it should be any different than normal (with Ember Data).  If you're having trouble with it you should post the code that you've tried to use and any errors that you're getting.  If you can post a JSBin illustrating the problem it would be even better.

Comment: I tacked in some basic stuff and clarified my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can attach `EmberFire.Object` to a specific URL that is associated with the post. You'll need the post_id to do that:

```js
App.PostRoute = Ember.Router.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return EmberFire.Object.create({
      ref: new Firebase("https://embertest2.firebaseio.com/posts/" + params.post_id)
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this when I get home

Comment: Tried your suggestion, and received an error which I've added above.  I think it's because I'm not properly defining my Object? I'll keep playing around to see what I can come up with.

Comment: Is there a valid object at https://embertest2.firebaseio.com/posts/<post-id>? It seems like you're trying to access "id" from an object but there's not one stored at the URL.

Comment: I haven't set an ID, I assumed the one set by Firebase is the ID?

Comment: Yes, Firebase automatically sets the ID, but I'd verify that data is actually present at the location. I'd also use the non-minified version of emberFire and post the stack trace for the undefined error, that'll help with debugging!

Comment: I added the error code I'm getting, and again thank you so much for the help.  Feels like I'm just overlooking something simple.

Comment: Do you think you could add an example to the repo depicting the proper way to handle this type of routing? Something that shows posts and links to each post? Would be super helpful